# Best practice for handling wrong HTTP verbs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-verbs, controller-action

We have the recurring issue with either users reloading pages or attacks sending:

- POST to GET actions
- GET to POST actions.

Especially the hacking part floods our logs with errors while trying all kind of url parameters...

Obviously this results in a

> HttpException: A public action method 'xyz' was not found on controller 'abc'

- Should we add the *other* action as well and return 404 Not Found or 400 Bad Request?
- This isn't entirely an asp.net issue. How do other frameworks handle this?

We could also just filter the error messages but this seems kind of a cover up...

Comment: Have you considered to use **405 (Method Not Allowed)** to indicate that the resource exist, but the provided verb is not allowed against it? What can you see from the logs: is it a D-DOS attack or a path traversal or ???

Comment: Just lots of request in a short time with different url parameters, sometimes with SQL queries for injection which won't work either... For the 405 we would need to impelement the method as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, 405 needs manual labouring. For me it does seem like someone is using some sort of penetration testing tool against your site.